# unitize (unitise) or unify?

Tags: synonyms

I am about to collect information from multiple sources and transform them into one language/terminology.

I wonder what would be the correct term for this process?

Maybe a different word would fit even better?

Thanks!

Comment: "curate" would be my choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both would suit your meaning, although I'd go for 'unify' rather than 'unitise', as you can call it a 'unified language' afterwards.

How about 'collate' as an alternative?

Meanings from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collate)

> to gather or arrange in their proper sequence (the pages of a report,
>   the sheets of a book, the pages of several sets of copies, etc.).
>
> Computers. to merge (sequenced data from two or more data sets or files) to produce a new sequenced data set or file.